# Why are changes in temperature not affecting the functioning of semiconductors in my CPU?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

While studying Condensed Matter Physics, I have learned that the electrical conductivity of a semiconductor increases rapidly as a function of the temperature.

However, I am wondering: why is this not making a big difference in the way the transistors in the chip of my computer work, seeing how its temperature can vary widely?

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice to design electronic circuits in such a manner that the exact vales of the parameters (like transistor beta) of components used are not critical for the operation of the device. This can be acomplished using feedback loops. When the temperature raises it affects the properties of different components, and this changes can compensate each other if the device is properly designed. Also, processor is a digital device which can differentiate only between two states 0 and 1. The exact value of voltage can change in broad range and still corespond to the same binary state.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature severely affects processor performance, but modern processors use aggressive cooling and often adapt their frequency depending on the temperature and other factors (https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Impact-of-Temperature-on-Intel-CPU-Performance-606/)